# Did we swap top bars with Meta Stack Exchange?

Tags: bug, status-completed, meta, top-bar

As [announced](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/300829/new-top-bar-is-coming-to-the-stack-exchange-network?cb=1) the new top bar has rolled out on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com). However, the top bar over here on Meta Stack Overflow seems to have gone back to the old design, which I'm guessing is not on purpose:

[image]

Comment: Tempted to downvote since I don't want this to be fixed... :)

Comment: Oh wow, it is *so* much better. No, do not fix this.

Comment: @CodyGray Quick, [status-bydesign] it to lock the change in ;)

Comment: New tag: feature dequest

Comment: I guess when they enabled it on all sites for Moderators only, they forgot to add an exception for SO.

Comment: @Stijn *for Moderators only* did I miss something?

Comment: @Glorfindel see [the timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/300829): *"changes will roll out on meta.se and to Mods on all sites on Monday (9/18); Assuming no significant issues are discovered we will roll out to all sites within the next couple weeks"*

Comment: @Stijn thanks. I'm a moderator on Ask Different and it's not active there at the moment.

Comment: @Glorfindel should be active for moderators now!